# Script to access Firefox extension/add-on

Tags: firefox, youtube, download, firefox-addon

I use Firefox extension "Freemake YouTube to MP3 Converter", which places a "Download" link under every YouTube video/playlist.

My idea is to make a script that searches YouTube and uses Freemake to download the audio content of videos.

However, how could I write a script that uses the Freemake "Download" function?

This is a specific question but also a general question about how to access Firefox extensions/add-ons and their methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create an extension that simulates a click on the download button. It doesn't matter that the button came from an extension; once it's placed on the page, it acts like it's part of the page. The only hang-up you may encounter is that you would need to ensure your script only runs after the download button becomes available.

The way you run your code depends on how exactly you envision this working. Possibilities include a separate extension, hacking the Freemake extension, a user script, a bookmarklet, or an iMacros script.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!  I used Firebug to find out what commands are generated when I click on the Download button so that I can emulate them in a script.

I would like to have this script run automatically every one in a while.  It would collect and maintain information from other Internet sites also.  Is this a program I should write in Javascript or something on my computer itself, or should I use a user script or an iMacros script in the browser?

Comment: It depends on how you want to run it. Will you visit the pages and then want to click a button? Or do you want it to automatically visit a number of sites and do stuff? It also depends on what you mean by "collect and maintain information".

Comment: I want it to automatically visit a couple sites and do stuff, no button-clicking.  It will collect a list of songs from one site, search YouTube for each song sequentially, then use Freemake to automatically download MP3s if they are found, thus syncing a list of songs to my local computer. The maintaining information part is seeing what songs were/weren't synced and checking whether new songs have been added to the original list.
I imagine this is something I should write separate from the browser.

Comment: Writing your own extension is probably the way to go for something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help